# How to download .torrent files in bulk?

Tags: bittorrent, wget

I have 2000 links of `.torrent` files in `.txt` file in the following format:

```
http://torrage.com/torrent/57CB57A8D0BC355B28A850CA6707365CBACBBD4C.torrent
http://torrage.com/torrent/22AC2445EFCFE1DED424BAAC35EB122ABA4FC0CF.torrent
```

Each link is on a newline.

I used `wget -i /path/to/file_of_torrents.txt`.

It downloads the files but for some reason no file is able to be used. They are not in right format, perhaps. I don't know what the problem is with them.

But if I paste any link manually in a web browser it downloads perfectly in the right format to be used in a bittorrent client.

What is going wrong?

**Additional Information**

If i open the file in bitorrent client nothing happens bittorent client cannot read the file. and if I see the source it's encrypted and I don't see it as like a normal torrent file because in normal torrent files it has links of `announce.php` and servers, but if I download it with `wget` I can read anything in the source:

**source file downloaded by wget**

```
\8B\00\00\00\00\00\00\8D\BBStfѲwl\9B\9D\A4c۶\ED\CE\FF\B1m۶mtl\A7c\DBv:\C6\ED\BD\F7\C1>g\8Cs\EF]c\AD\97\AA5g\CD\F9\B0
\C0\C9mdcc\EBlcl\C2\CC\C2\ED\B0\E3f`pr02\B62q\A0766\A6\98ps22\B1\FC\88h\E1\E8\FE\DFX 3\FB\FF\CA\FDe\D8M\E8-\9C\FE\99f\E1\E06wr\FA\F7\BC\9D\F3O\A0\85\F1O'zc[kF\86\FFt\FA\8Bd\FB_B\B6v&6?-\9C\9ClLl\FE   \FF\97"\F3\FFU̿\8B1\FEo\DB\A1\FE\C2\F9\BFt\FE\BD\B0\FF\A5\C6\FE\FF\B6\88\FF\A9\F9@7[\80\B3\E3_GGw\E3*\B2s\B1s\FD;\F4?\97\E1\EA\EAJo\CE\C2\F2/[\A636\E1\E0\FE\B4\FE\BBz6.n\D5\ED1\C0\D6\D5hk0\9B:\D8Z\FF\C7\FE\9B\9B9\FFg\A9\E3Ff&\FF\90eb\E46v01r\FAK\F9\E9\FE\B7#\CE\FF)F\A5(\A9H,4rt$\A6#8X\98\D8KX\FCt0r\A2\FE{\FEI\B2\B0\B5!\FC\E5Z0\B1\B03\B22s\B0\B3r\99pr\9B\D8\DB,l\CCظ\D5T\C5\E98Y\B9-lLm9\A6@:\80\B3\C3?\89@V.f\C6\FF~M\FE\F3O\8C\B5  \C0\C2\F8\8F \D3\FF\F8L\D8\FE
```

**Source of same file downloded from web browser**

```
d8:announce23:udp://tracker.ccc.de:8013:announce-listll23:udp://tracker.ccc.de:80el26:udp://tracker.istole.it:80el37:http://tracker.publicbt.com0/announceel35:udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80el32:udp://tracker.ccc.de:80/announceel30:http://tracker.ccc.de/announceel38:udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announceel36:http://tracker.publicbt.com/announceel38:http://exodus.desync.com:6969/announceel32:udp://www.h33t.com:3310/announceee7:comment59:Torrent downloaded from torrent cache at http://torrage.com10:created by37:ruTorrent (PHP Class - Adrien Gibrat)13:creation datei1360427649e8:encoding5:UTF-84:infod13:file-durationli4927ei0ei0ei0ei0ee10:file-mediali0ei-1ei-1ei-1ei-1ee5:filesld6:lengthi737021634e4:pathl26:s4a-tpb.afk.hdrip.xvid.avieed6:lengthi4239360e4:pathl4:Subs26:s4a-tpb.afk.hdrip.xvid.subeed6:lengthi40513e4:pathl4:Subs26:s4a-tpb.afk.hdrip.xvid.idxeed6:lengthi4986e4:pathl26:s4a-tpb.afk.hdrip.xvid.nfoeed6:lengthi353e4:pathl44:Torrent Downloaded From ExtraTorrent.com.txteee4:name27:TPB.AFK.2013.HDRip.XviD-S4A12:pie
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that no file is able to be used and that they are not in the right format (when you use `wget -i`)? *What happens* when you try to use them? What error do you get? Please provide more details (by editing your question). Thanks.

Comment: Also, what happens if you just try downloading a *single* file with `wget`, by giving the URL on the command line (i.e., not by using `-i`)? Is that file usable?

Comment: @EliahKagan same results weather i use -i or not

Comment: I tried downloading single file but the results are same

Comment: This is strange. I'm able to reproduce this with `wget`, and with `curl` also (both with and without the `-L` flag), which suggests strongly that it's not a bug in `wget`.

Comment: yes its not the bug of wget may its the server who have encrypted the files ? is that possible if we download the files from browser its works fine becase the server dencrpt the files on the fly ?

Comment: This might be by design, but assuming I understand correctly what you mean, no. The relationship between the client and server are essentially the same, whether your user agent is a traditional web browser, or wget. Instead, it seems that, for some reason, the wrong encoding is being used in wget and curl, but the right encoding is used in Chromium (my browser) and perhaps other browsers. This could be a bug in wget and curl, or it could be a bug on the server. Either way, even if my hypothesis is right, we'll need to figure out better why this is happening (or find some other app that works).

Comment: @Rinzwind This is interesting, since it's not compressed when downloaded with Chromium or lynx (but is when downloaded with wget, curl, or links2).

Comment: Now torrage has some protection from mass downloading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `wget http://torrage.com/torrent/57CB57A8D0BC355B28A850CA6707365CBACBBD4C.torrent -O test.gz`  && `gunzip test.gz`
2. `more test.gz`

> result

`d8:announce23:udp://tracker.ccc.de:8013:announce-listll23:udp://tracker.ccc.de:8
0el26:udp://tracker.istole.it:80el3`

- rest deleted since most of the content seems not to be allowed ;)
- The file you downloaded is zipped. gunzip does not unzip .torrent so I added a -O and a gunzip

---

How about these 4 commands for all files:

```
cd /path/to/
wget -i file_of_torrents.txt
rename.ul torrent torrent.gz *.torrent
gunzip *.gz
```

Just make sure you work in an empty directory (otherwise files might get renamed or gunzipped that are not intended to).

Comment: yes exactly goal is to download 2000 files how can we use this command to download the files from .txt file ?

Comment: aweeeeeeeesommmmmmmmmeeee thattttttttttssss ittttttttttttt you are masterrrrrrr salute to rizwind

Comment: you made me blush @YousafEhsan :+)